# Временные файлы Tomcat 8

Tags: spring, tomcat

через web-сервис(Spring) загружаю xls файлы, далее отправляются в обработку в java. Но у меня почему -то томкат сохраняет эти самые файлы, которые я загрузил и помещает их в место, откуда был запущен томкат, будь это батник с рабочего стола, либо из папки \bin.

Подскажите, можно ли как-то избавиться от этого? чтобы не сохранял эти файлы?
Спасибо

в файле web.xml добавил код

```
<filter>
    <display-name>springMultipartFilter</display-name>
    <filter-name>springMultipartFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springMultipartFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Далее через контроллер получаю файлы и передаю в метод

```
public String routeList(@RequestParam(value = "routes") MultipartFile routeFile,
                         @RequestParam(value = "wagons") MultipartFile wagonFile
```

в файле context.xml на томкате строка

```
<Context reloadable="true" allowCasualMultipartParsing="true">
```

из контроллера, файлы передаются в метод обработки и преобразования в тип File

```
public class MultipartFileToFile {
// Подключаем логгер
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MultipartFileToFile.class);

public static File convertToFile;

public static File multipartToFile(MultipartFile multipart) {
    try {
        convertToFile = new File(multipart.getOriginalFilename());
        convertToFile.createNewFile();
        try(FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(convertToFile)) {
            fileOutputStream.write(multipart.getBytes());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Ошибка конвертации файла - {}", e.getMessage());
    }
    return convertToFile;
}
}
```

После идут уже в обработку, где вытаскивается информация, там используется POI Apache

Comment: Покажите код загрузки файлов.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Добавил код

Comment: @Владислав маловато кода. Покажите, как Вы этот файл обрабатываете, что с ним делаете.

Comment: @zolt Добавил еще кода. Вот сейчас опять я загружал 4 файла и на рабочем столе создались ecxel файлы такие же, которые я загружал, с тем же содержимым. Только имя кривое, так как названия файлов русскими буквами

Comment: Я понял, файл создается и далее используется для перезаписи, так как я в загружаемый файл вношу изменения и далее отдаю его обратно, если во время работы удалить этот временный файл, то и в итоге скачать его нельзя будет. Вопрос теперь в другом, могу ли я эти файлы хранить где-то в папке томката, а не на рабочем столе например, откуда был запущен томкат?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы временные файлы создавались в нужной Вам директории, её нужно указывать в конструкторе. Можно использовать конструктор [File(String parent, String child)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-). В качестве parent может выступать папка для временных файлов в томкате. Путь до нее Вы можете получить через`System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")`

Comment: Спасибо большое, вроде получилось